# Why is public key cryptography not widely used in governments?

Tags: public-key, signature, pki

Are there any practical limitations? Govt driving license, passport, SSN could be digitally signed making it easy for anyone to validate. They can have a qr code in them which can be easily validated using an android or ios app offline if the corresponding public key is pre installed. This will make fake ids impossible. Why is it not done even in developed countries like united states?

Comment: I voted to close as off-topic since this is about security policies, not cryptography *per se*. You should ask this on [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A QR code is easily copied. Putting a digital signature on a QR code on each ID won't prevent making a copy of a valid ID. It won't even prevent changing the photo on the copy, unless the photo is available from an online database (and if we have this, we hardly need the signature in the QR code).

Comment: @fgrieu Agree photo can be changed in smaller ids. Encrypting/encoding photo will require a huge qr code. may be possible with passport. At least other details can be validated offline

Comment: @fkraiem can you please move the question to Security.SE?